# change android textview color from a string

Tags: android

Hey i am creating a android textview which contains come from json..
It is fine but i want to change color of the part of the text view.. dont know how

here is my details-

```
JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(result);

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject getjson=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

s= "Title: "            +getjson.getString("tender_title")+
   "\n\nTender id: "    +getjson.getString("tender_id")+
   "\n\nReference no:\n"+getjson.getString("tender_reference_no")+
   "\n\nQuantity: "     +getjson.getString("tender_item_details_quantity");

}

TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText(s);
```

On the above code is fine..that sets all the value in the text view but i want to change the color of **"Title" ,"Tender id", "Quantity"** etc.. from above string **s** please help

Comment: what does the string contains, black,white , or hex values of colors?

Comment: @Arju thanx for reply.. now this textview set as white but i want to change part of this text to yellow color..

Comment: @Brett if your problem is resolved, you should pick the most helpful answer as a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the text as html:

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("your <font color='#FF0000'>content</font>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [spans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html)

Example:

```
{
   final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");
   final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

   // Span to set text color to some RGB value
   final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

   // Span to make text bold
   sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // Set the text color for first 4 characters
   sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // make them also bold
   yourTextView.setText(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution specific to your case:

Update your code as follows:

```
JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(result);
Spanned spannedStr = null;
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject getjson = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    spannedStr = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(getColorString("Title:"), getjson.getString("tender_title"), "\n\n",
            getColorString("Tender id:"), getjson.getString("tender_title"), "\n\n",
            getColorString("Reference no:"), getjson.getString("tender_title"), "\n\n",
            getColorString("Quantity:"), getjson.getString("tender_title"));

}
TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText(spannedStr);
```

Define a helper method in the same class and use it:

```
private Spanned getColorString(String str) {
    return Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFF00'>" + str + "</font>");
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Spanned also for that.

```
 Spanned sText=Html.fromHtml("<font color="#C3003">Title:</font> "  );

txt.setText(sText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(text);

 WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), text.length, (text +      
 nextString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 myTextView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```